# Groupby Year and Month in datetime in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am exporting month from datetime column.

My data is as follows:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| Payment Date | Payable Amount |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2016/5/31    |             20 |
| 2016/5/28    |             50 |
| 2016/5/21    |             70 |
| 2016/5/20    |             10|
| 2016/5/15    |             150|
+--------------+----------------+
```

I have tried with following code:

```
data.groupby([data['Payment Date'].dt.year,data['Payment Date'].dt.month])['Payable Amount'].sum()
```

Which gives output as following columns:

Year

Month

Amount

Please note that I have tried with pd.Grouper('M) which throws an error as Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'

I expect result like this.

```
+--------------+----------------+
| Payment Date | Payable Amount |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2016/5/1    |             300 |
| 2016/6/1    |             400 |
| 2016/7/1    |             500 |
| 2016/8/1    |             550 |
| 2016/9/1    |             600 |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please fix your desired output to be more consistent with your data.

Comment: I have edited the desired output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby`, flooring "Payment Date" to the beginning of the month:

```
(data.groupby(df['Payment Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))['Payable Amount']
     .sum()
     .reset_index())

  Payment Date  Payable Amount
0   2016-05-01             300
```

The subtraction with the offset object is meant to get the starting date for that month:

```
df['Payment Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

0   2016-05-01
1   2016-05-01
2   2016-05-01
3   2016-05-01
4   2016-05-01
Name: Payment Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you explain why are you subtracting, and I couldn't understand the code...

Comment: @krishna31 Edited with a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Grouper should work *provided the Payment Date column has datetime type*. Demo:

```
t = '''Payment Date | Payable Amount
2016/5/31    |             20
2016/5/28    |             30
2016/5/21    |             40
2017/5/20    |             50
2017/5/15    |             60'''

t = re.sub(r'[ \t]+\|[ \t]+', ',', t)


df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=['Payment Date'])

print(df)
```

outputs:

```
  Payment Date  Payable Amount
0   2016-05-31              20
1   2016-05-28              30
2   2016-05-21              40
3   2017-05-20              50
4   2017-05-15              60
```

Then:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Payment Date', freq='MS')).sum()
```

outputs:

```
              Payable Amount
Payment Date                
2016-05-01                90
2016-06-01                 0
2016-07-01                 0
2016-08-01                 0
2016-09-01                 0
2016-10-01                 0
2016-11-01                 0
2016-12-01                 0
2017-01-01                 0
2017-02-01                 0
2017-03-01                 0
2017-04-01                 0
2017-05-01               110
```